# How to assign dictionary results to individual variables in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.6

I have this result:

```
{'orderId': 1234567, 'price': '20.5', 'qty': '125', 'status': 'open'}
{'orderId': 7654321, 'price': '15.5', 'qty': '15', 'status': 'open'}
{'orderId': 9876543, 'price': '32.0', 'qty': '102', 'status': 'open'}
```

I want to assign each **orderID to individual variable**, so I can do something to each of them.

Above result is gained thru filtering code as follow:

```
orders = product.get_open_orders(product='sample')

keys = ['orderId', 'price', 'qty', 'status']
res = [{k: d[k] for k in keys} for d in orders]

for status in res:
    if status['status'] == 'open':
        print(status)
```

Comment: Can you show some example of what you want to do with them? So far I don't see why `status['orderId']` would not be enough.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your desired output format?!

Comment: @Norrius Yes, i can get all orderId with status['orderId']. The results are now showing all numbers. I want to extract each orderId number and assign to variable, like orderId1=1234567. I am using python wrapper, such that to cancel order, I need to key in the orderId.

Comment: @Cleb Output format is orderId1=1234567 , orderId2=7654321 , orderId3=9876543. This is after assigning each orderId to respective variable.

Comment: You can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5036700/1534017)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a sequence of enumerated items, the correct data structure for that is a `list`:

```
orders = []
for status in res:
    if status['status'] == 'open':
        orders.append(status['orderId'])
print(orders)  # [1234567, 7654321, 9876543]
print(orders[0], orders[2])  # 1234567 9876543
```

Or, in more idiomatic Python:

```
orders = [status['orderId'] for status in res if status['status'] == 'open']
print(orders)  # [1234567, 7654321, 9876543]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I can work with these codes you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Just do `status['orderId']`

```
count = 1
for status in res:
    if status['status'] == 'open':
        print(status)
        orderId = status['orderId']
        eval("orderId"+str(count) + "=" + "orderId")
```

This will create `orderId0`, `orderId1` ...

Comment: Yes, I got this result:1234567  7654321  9876543. I want to be able to extract this individually to assign to variable like (orderId1=1234567 , orderId2=7654321 , orderId3=9876543).

Comment: Why dont you try using eval. I will edit the above code

Comment: Pls edit above code to show how I can capture all the orderId and placing them to variables. Not familiar yet with eval() function usage.